# How can I convert a Mac locale file to something human readable?

Tags: macos, internationalization

I'd like to see what's in the LC_CTYPE files in */usr/share/locale/**, but they are binary files. Is there a tool that will make a human readable version, or a specification of their format somewhere?

I'm mostly interested in seeing what each locale puts in the various POSIX named character classes.

I would have liked to tag this "locale", but apparently that tag doesn't exist and I don't have the rep for it.

Comment: Using the file command it should tell you what they are. Possibly a gettext file.

Comment: No such luck with file.

Comment: This may be of interest then, since it's not gettext, but C's locale lib: https://linux.die.net/man/1/localedef